# Redmine search results shortens the subject of an issue (...)

Tags: redmine

I would like to change the layout of the search results for issues. If the subject of an issue is long, it gets shortend with ...
[image: sceenshot search results]
How and where can I change the behaviour? I would like to have always the full title of an issue.

Thank you for your help!